# Как сжать BMP без потери MIME TYPE и всех заголовков?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bmp

У меня есть BMP-файл, в нём есть только чёрный и белый цвета, разрешение 1200 x 500, - обычный текст и баркод.

Как уменьшить размер файла хотя бы до 200кб, без потери MIME TYPE и всех заголовков? Есть какие либо работающие варианты или библиотеки?

Comment: можно попробовать в 1 бит на пиксель сохранить. получится в районе 75кб. А можно просто попробовать зазипить то, что есть.

Comment: дайте ссылку на файл

Comment: @nörbörnën - сжать именно и подразумевает сжать и при этом обычно размер уменьшается. Иногда существенно.

Comment: @KoVadim размер файла или размер холста?

Comment: а 200кб это о размере хоста или о размере файла

Comment: @KoVadim я генерировал файл `bmp`, он весит 2.3мб, [напустил на него старый добрый libgd](https://pastebin.com/j8AUx4bL) и получил файл размером 1.7мб за счёт включенной компрессии. это то, что нужно автору вопроса?

Comment: @KoVadim сорян, я - не внимательный )

Comment: да, только 1.7 мб это немного много.

Comment: @KoVadim готов )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться библиотекой [node-gd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd)

> GD graphics library, libgd, C++ bindings for Node.js. With node-gd you
> can easily create, manipulate, open and save paletted and true color
> images from and to a variety of image formats including JPEG, PNG, GIF
> and BMP.

Для демонстрации работы программы я сгенерировал [bmp-файл](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norbornen/stackoverflow-practice/main/src/bmp-1/EAN13code.bmp) со штрихкодом, его размер равен `2,3M`.

```
const path = require('path');
const gd = require('node-gd');

const filesrc = path.join(__dirname, './EAN13code.bmp');
const filedest = path.join(__dirname, './EAN13code.gd.bmp');

(async () => {
  const img = await gd.openBmp(filesrc);
  img.grayscale();
  img.trueColorToPalette(0, 4);
  await img.saveBmp(filedest, 1);
  img.destroy();
})();
```

Получился [файл](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norbornen/stackoverflow-practice/main/src/bmp-1/EAN13code.gd4.bmp) размером `60K`.

---

Вся суть сводится к трансформации "широкой" палитры применяемой в файле в "узкую" палитру методом [trueColorToPalette](https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd/blob/master/docs/index.md#gdimagetruecolortopaletteditherflag-colorswanted) и сохранении с компрессией методом [saveBmp](https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd/blob/master/docs/index.md#gdimagesavebmppath-compression). Кстати, `colorsWanted` можно установить значение 2 и тогда [картинка получается](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norbornen/stackoverflow-practice/main/src/bmp-1/EAN13code.gd2.bmp) размером `53K`.

Comment: Блин, библиотека работает, но на винде ее нельзя поставить, к сожалению. Есть ли что-то подобное для винды? В любом случае, спасибо за либу.

Comment: не знал об этом и удивлён. посмотрю вечером на виртуальной винде. какая версия винды? питон установлен?

Comment: Да, питон стоит, винда 10.  Даже на офф репозитории написано: 'Sorry, will not build on Windows'. Грустно блен

Comment: а на большом so есть вопросы про установку с принятыми ответами... надо пробовать. кстати, есть ещё одна [библиотека](https://github.com/vonderheide/mono-bitmap), можно попробовать с её помощью провернуть что-то подобное тому, что я предложил в ответе

Comment: но на моей тестовой картинке библиотека валится из-за того, что картинка с компрессией (header.compression !== RGB_BITMAP_COMPRESSION)